# Transfer content from Clipboard to google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a Google macro, the app script looks as follows

1. Creates a new sheet with name of current date.
2. move the sheet top of google sheet.
3. formats the sheet by freezing column1 and row1
4. Automatically transfer the content of clipboard into google sheet.

My code:

```
var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+4", "ddMMM"));

if (yourNewSheet != null) {
    activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(yourNewSheet);
}

yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
activeSpreadsheet.moveActiveSheet(1);
yourNewSheet.setName(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+4", "ddMMM"));

yourNewSheet.getRange('A1').activate();
///need code to move the content from clipboard to google sheet.

yourNewSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
yourNewSheet.setFrozenColumns(1);
yourNewSheet.getRange('1:1').activate();
yourNewSheet.getActiveRangeList().setTextRotation(45);
```

I'm bit clueless on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Clipboard is in your browser, while Apps Script runs in Google's servers

Comment: shouldn't the google app script have access to browser's clipboard ?

Comment: why? There is no requirement for Google Apps script to be run from a browser. You can configure functions to run in a variety of configurations, and an active UI instance is not required in most.